# Parents working abroad

Tags: united-states, school, parental-rights

Alice and Bob are working abroad in a foreign country. They have a child named Charlie. All three are US citizens with valid US passports. Charlie is 16 years old.

If they decide to sent Charlie back to the United States to finish high school there, are there any laws governing this?

Can a 16 year old just fly back alone? Are there any restrictions in place where the parents would need to be present physically, like renting a place or Charlie registering for school? Would there be any obstacles where Charlie would need Power of Attorney?

Comment: Yes, a 16 year old can fly internationally since they have a passport. A letter from both parents may help. And these days almost anything can be done remotely.

Comment: What would the child be able to do in terms of guardianship? Would they have to go straight to a foster home?

Comment: Why would they need to be in a foster home? They have parents, just not right there. There are lots of teenagers attending boarding schools in the US, as one example, and some of them have no parents in the US.

Comment: I was planning to go to the same public school before I left

Comment: I see no reason in particular why arranging housing (in your parent's name) would be an issue. My father finished his last year in high school by himself after his parents died. A neighbor friend kept an eye on things.

Comment: If attending public school, the school district may expect the student to attend school where at least one of the parent's live. Obtaining an exception would require investigating the policy of the particular jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a 16 year old just fly back alone?

Legally, nothing is preventing a 16 year old from flying alone, this is if the airline allows it, and not all airlines do

[AA](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/unaccompanied-minors.jsp) :

> We don’t allow children to travel alone when their trips include:
>
> ```
> Flights on another airline including codeshare and oneworld® partners
> Ground or co-terminal connections where the child must transfer from one local airport to another
> The last flight of the day from the final connection city (unless it’s the only flight)
> Overnight connecting flights
> ```

| Age | Restictions |
| --- | --- |
| 15-17 | • Unaccompanied minor service optional, service fee still applies |
|  | • Gate escort and guardian contact required |
|  | • Nonstop flights, or any connecting flight through AA hub airports in the US |

In AA's case, someone still needs to be checking in person and picking the child at arrival

Delta hoever gives no special requirements for minors 15+ years

[Delta](https://www.delta.com/us/en/children-infant-travel/overview)

Comment: This is a good partial answer.